# Is there a way to improve linting errors highlight in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, tslint

Currently eslint/tslint highlighting for issues/errors is super invisible (comparing, for example, to Atom). Its almost impossible to catch the issue - find the small green highlight zone (see screenshot)

VSCode:
[image: VSCode screenshot]

Atom:
[image: Atom screenshot]

**Question is not relevant since June 2018 (VSCode now has awesome highlights)**

Comment: Did you found a way to improve highlighting? I searched open/closed issues on GitHub about this but there are too many. Maybe this is something that installing a theme can improve?

Comment: @GustavoCoelho nope, asked team in gitter, seems like its fine for them ATM :)

Comment: There is an issue in VSCode for this, please vote: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16222

Answer (score 17):

Simple. I use 2 extensions for that:

**[Error Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens)** (usernamehw.errorlens) for highlight the entire line and show on real time the error diagnostic

**[Error Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IgorSbitnev.error-gutters)** (igorsbitnev.error-gutters) for put error icons next of line number

Both look like this:

[image]

Comment: Errorlens is great!

Comment: That should be an accepted solution for now, I couldn't agree more

Comment: Error Lens already includes Error Gutters. Simply enable Icons in Error Lens.

Answer (score 5):

For those who would like a partial solution for this you can actually open up the console in vscode on the PROBLEMS tab to display all errors on across your application grouped by file.

I would prefer the inline visualised approach, but this does resolve this problem more or less.

[image]

To open the PROBLEMS tab, click CMD+Shift+M on Mac.

Not sure about windows.