# What should I do to highlight error lines after running code in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to highlight error line when I finish running code in vscode. Just like this code I wanna highlight 45 and 57 lines. What can i do?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\onedrive\L_ML\L_ML_W3_Lab06-09\L_ML_W3_Lab06.py", line 57, in <module>
    dj_db_tmp, dj_dw_tmp = compute_gradient_logistic(X_tmp, y_tmp, w_tmp, b_tmp)
  File "f:\onedrive\L_ML\L_ML_W3_Lab06-09\L_ML_W3_Lab06.py", line 45, in compute_gradient_logistic
    dj_dw = dj_dw[j] + err_i * X[i,j]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

like this picture

[image]

use yellow highlight error line

Comment: you have to add a problem matcher to your run task, or use `Ctrl+Click` in the terminal to go to the line

Comment: thx bro, but my question not this , invalid index not in problem matcher. it in the outpoint matcher. i want outpoint abnormal issue feedback in my code.

Comment: you can define any line in the problem matcher to extract filename and line number

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57227604/836330 for the Error Lens extension.